# answers.ros.org comment formatting

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You used to be able to use backticks for `inline code`, * for *italics* and **bold**, and even [name links](http://answers.ros.org) in comments on this site, but lately, all of these characters just show up as literals in comments.

How can this be fixed?

**EDIT**

According to answer from @georgebrindeiro there is a github site for reporting these kinds of bugs.  Perusing that issue tracker revealed [this bug report](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/42) complaining about this same issue.  It was closed with the argument being that significant formatting isn't really expected in the comments.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102751/answers.ros.org-comment-formatting/) by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9031 on 2013-11-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-19**:
`inline code` *italics* **bold** [name links](http://answers.ros.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The proper way to deal with this is issue, I guess, is [starting a new issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/new).

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-19**:
Thanks for the link, I was unaware this site had a github.

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-11-20**:
No problem, I wasn't aware either until I made a similar question. By the way, most things in ROS have migrated to GitHub, so if you have any issue with the core libraries in ROS or infrastructure stuff (ROS answers, Wiki, etc), the best way to contact devs is through that channel.